# Find Customer that operates in same city

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have node with Customers, second node is Addresses

There is relation Customer LOCATED_IN Address

I would like to get all customers which are located in same city, return city, count and customer names sorted by count desc

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(a:Address)
WITH a.city as city, count(*) as count
WHERE count > 1
RETURN city, count, collect(c.name)
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

c not defined (line 4, column 29 (offset: 120))
"RETURN city, count, collect(c.name)"
                             ^
Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax

Query works fine if I remove "collect(c.name)" but ehmm then I miss little info I would like to get...

Answer (score 3):

As TrueDub says, you need to bring everything you want to return with you in the `WITH` clause.
But you can't bring `a.city`, `count(*)` *and* `c` and expect `count(*)` to be the count of customers in a city.
The reason is that, in order to count customers per city, you need to aggregate the customers.
But here you bring the individual customer (`c`) with you, and bringing the individual customer prevents the aggregation of customers.
That's why you get `1`, because counting without aggregation just means counting the individual result item.

You can easily solve this by bringing two things in the `WITH` clause: the address/city, and the collection of customers. When you bring individual addresses/cities and aggregate the customers, you get the aggregation of customers per city.

```
WITH a.city, COLLECT(c) as customers
```

Then you can filter on the size of that collection.

```
WHERE SIZE(customers) > 1
```

---

An additional and unsolicited note: the way your query works now, it reads off properties before doing the filtering.
This is not efficient, since it reads properties for result items that may then be discarded.
Depending on what your `:Address` nodes look like<sup>1</sup>, you may be able to do the collecting and filtering without touching any properties.
This would be desirable for performance.
See **Tip #4: Defer Property Access** in Michael Hunger's [5 Secrets to More Effective Neo4j 2.2. Query Tuning](http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-query-tuning/).

```
MATCH (customer:Customer)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(address:Address)
WITH address, COLLECT(customer) as customersAtAddress
WHERE SIZE(customersAtAddress) > 1
RETURN address.city as city,
       SIZE(customersAtAddress) as customerCount,
       EXTRACT(customer IN customersAtAddress | customer.name) as customerNames
```

Now the query excludes those addresses that only have one customer before fetching any properties and the customers are in a collection per address. Since the customers are in a collection, we use `EXTRACT` to go through the collection and read off the name of each customer. `EXTRACT` returns a new collection, so your result will look something like.

```
city        customerCount    customerNames
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Säby        2                [Anders Järhed, Matilda Fridlund]
 Frinnaryd   3                [Bo-Erik Jonsson, Annelie Sjöström, Ulf Eliasson]
```

> <sup>1</sup> I say "depending on what your `:Address` nodes look like, because I don't know whether you have many address nodes that share a single city. If you do, then you have a different problem. The query that I suggest (and your own query, also) will give you collections of customers per address node. If you have two address nodes for the city `Säby`, then you will get two result items for `Säby`, with two different collections of customers. The solution is probably to change your model a little, and move the city to its own node, with a relationship to the different addresses which 'have' that city. Let me know if this is the case and maybe I can advise on that.

Finally, the query above calculates the size of the collection twice. That's not so very expensive, and the value is probably cached by the query engine. But in case you want to make sure, you can add another `WITH` clause to calculate the value once and bind it to an identifier. The query then comes out as

```
MATCH (customer:Customer)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(address:Address)
WITH address, COLLECT(customer) as customersAtAddress
WITH address, customersAtAddress, COUNT(customersAtAddress) as customerCount
WHERE SIZE(customersAtAddress) > 1
RETURN address.city as city,
       customerCount,
       EXTRACT(customer IN customersAtAddress | customer.name) as customerNames
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to bring c into the WITH clause, like so:

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(a:Address)
WITH a.city as city, count(*) as count, c
WHERE count > 1
RETURN city, count, collect(c.name)
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but actually it returns : (no rows)

Comment: Btw I know there is a match, because if I put a query like this: 
`MATCH (c:Customer)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(a:Address)
WITH a.city as city, count(*) as count
WHERE count > 1
RETURN city, count
ORDER BY count DESC;`
It returns 7 rows

Comment: +1 @TrueDub is correct that you have to bring everything in the `WITH` clause that you want to return. The reason you get no results is that you bring individual `a`:s and `c`:s. The `count(*)` can't aggregate anything when you do that, so the value of `count(*)` is always `1`. Since `1` is not `> 1`, nothing passes through the filter. I added an answer about that and with suggestions how to improve the query.